# What kind of encryption is this?

Tags: encryption

Hey can someone please tell me what kind of encryption this is? This is not the whole encrypted code but you should still be able to tell what it is from the structure.

`HC1:6BFOXN*TS0BI$ZDFRH5+FPWF9EIZ.0769Y3S3XHP+56R5-F9/17BOMEY4/OBMMD/GPWBILC9GGBYPLR-SNH10EQ928GEQW2DVJ5UL8W2BM8Q.L8SNCYNAK+FA7E7:4N3IK/4S1ARO4R48/3987CGSK37F/HS$*S-CK9B92FF9B9LW4G%89-8CNNM3LK.GVD9O-OEF82E9GX8$G10QVGB3O1KO-OAGJM*KIE9MIHJ6WH5URT2O%DSUES$8R12CT28M.SY$NTWA 34+5E1-ST*QGTA4W7.Y7U015RD3J5:ZSINIT.958G+7I5.M438 -H9:6JSN:U70+VD-FMJQE$NEV3V+NPD545T.*KKZUM7HR2FV1IJP17MVMGJ+:6Z$V1-I9BUDO33.G:LF`

Comment: Already closed, but I'll note that for the vast majority of modern encryption it's impossible to tell what encryption scheme was used from the ciphertext alone.